# Data from database is overloading PHP's memory limit

Tags: php

I'm developing a report where I write the syntax to retrieve data from database, but my result data is huge.  It's causing an error like this:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2024 bytes)

It's also displaying the report page slowly.

How I can solve this problem, avoid this error and make this page faster?

Comment: You can try to change [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Comment: is data is more than 2mb in database ?

Comment: I quit sure that my data is more than 2 MB for executing.

Comment: but I have limitation for memory_limit so should I redesign my sql inquiry too ?

Comment: If you're able to do the query, but the result's too big, you may well be trying to fetch all the rows at once.  For a huge result set, that could cause issues.  Depending on what you have to do with the data, you might be able to rearrange things so you fetch one row at a time and process/output it.

Comment: I know some ideas from other that they load data to xml first then display data from xml file. Is it good solution to do that ?

Comment: The enterprise wonks will be all over me for saying this, but XML is hardly ever a good idea internally, particularly if your memory's limited.  It can be quite verbose, and in most cases would take up more memory than the raw query result.  If you're outputting XML, it might be an option...but you'll want to output it directly, not buffer it.